# EF Core 8 on .NET 8 - mismatch behavior lazy vs eager loading

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

This 'problem' is reproducible by the following git repository:

https://github.com/tschmit/EFCLazyVsEagerWeird

I have the following entities (lots of lines omitted):

```cs
class Folder 
{
    public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }  
    public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }
}

class File 
{
    public Int32 FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Log> Logs { get; set; }
}

class Log 
{
    public Int32? FolderId { get; set; }
    public virtual Folder Folder { get; set; }

    public Int32? FileId { get; set; }
    public virtual File File { get; set; }

    public bool IsError { get; set; }
}
```

Configured as follow (lazy loading enabling omitted but it is enabled):

```cs
public class FolderEFConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Folder> {
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Folder> b) 
    {
        b.HasMany(x => x.Files)
         .WithOne(y => y.Folder)
         .HasForeignKey(y => y.FolderId).IsRequired();
    }
}

public class LogEFConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Log> 
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Log> b) 
    {
        //...
        b.HasOne(x => x.File)
         .WithMany(fl => fl.Logs)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.FileId);

        b.HasOne(x => x.Folder)
         .WithMany(fd => fd.Logs)
         .HasForeignKey(x => x.FolderId);
        //...
    }
}
```

The following code fails when printing `fd.Logs.Count()`:

```cs
using AppContext ctx = new ActapiContext(conf.GetConnectionString("abc"));
var fd = await ctx.Set<Folder>().Where(x => x.InnerRef == "XXXXX").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
Console.WriteLine(fd?.Files.Count());
Console.WriteLine(fd?.Logs.Count());
```

And I get this error:

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values

On the other hand, the following code runs fine:

```cs
using AppContext ctx = new ActapiContext(conf.GetConnectionString("abc"));

var fd = await ctx.Set<Folder>().Include(x => x.Logs).Where(x => x.InnerRef == "XXXXX").FirstOrDefaultAsync();

Console.WriteLine(fd?.Files.Count());
Console.WriteLine(fd?.Logs.Count());
```

So lazy loading is effective for `Files`, but not for `Logs`. Why?

I will also be grateful for any clue helping to find why. I tried to reproduce the behavior on a small project without success (that is everything runs fine when I use a blog / post  sample with log on both blog and post).

Keep digging, I find an update in the MCD:

```sql
alter table Logs add IsError bit default 0
```

which sets a lot of line with `IsError` to null, so the Log entity can't be materialized.

By replacing the MCD update with

```sql
alter table Logs add IsError bit not null default 0
```

everything runs fine, **BUT**: why does the eager loading runs in both cases (good MCD and wrong MCD)?

the SQL behind the cases:

```sql
-- EAGER LOADING
SELECT [t].[Id], [t].[Title], [l].[Id], [l].[BlogId], [l].[Date], 
    [l].[IsError], [l].[PostId], [l].[Text]
FROM (
    SELECT TOP(1) [b].[Id], [b].[Title]
    FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [b]
    WHERE [b].[Id] = 1
) AS [t]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Logs] AS [l] ON [t].[Id] = [l].[BlogId]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]
```

```sql
-- LAZY LOADING
SELECT TOP(1) [b].[Id], [b].[Title]
FROM [dbo].[Blogs] AS [b]
WHERE [b].[Id] = 1

-- then
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [l].[Id], [l].[BlogId], [l].[Date], [l].[IsError], [l].[PostId], [l].[Text]
FROM [dbo].[Logs] AS [l]
WHERE [l].[BlogId] = @__p_0',N'@__p_0 int',@__p_0=1
```

still: why does the eager loading runs in both cases (good MCD and wrong MCD)?

Comment: Have you tried configuring the `Folder`->`Logs` relationship in the `FolderEFConfiguration` the same way you did for `Files`?

Comment: @julealgon , I just did: same behavior: OK wiht include, KO without.

Comment: It looks like you'd have to add more information so we can reproduce this.

Comment: Definitely an odd behaviour. The null-able Boolean with non-nullable property would pose a problem, though I don't grasp why it would manifest in the lazy load scenario and not the eager load one, especially if pulling the same row(s). Are you sure both scenarios were called for the exact same Folder? With the null-able column I would run the eager load and capture the SQL being run, inspecting the # of rows returned vs. what is run for the lazy load call.

Comment: @StevePy, yes I'm sure. As it involves an "existing database then ef" scenario the elaboration of a simple piece of code takes a few time but I'm working on it.

Comment: here is a git repository illustrating the behaviors: https://github.com/tschmit/EFCLazyVsEagerWeird

Comment: While it's weird behavior it also shows that the class model and the database schema should match, i.e. `IsError` should be a `bool?` if the database column is nullable. That aside, maybe the generated queries can shed some light on this?

Comment: @GertArnold, you are right, things should be right, not wrong :). Here is the SQL, which does not enlighten me.